# Why do some meshes have a diagonal line through quads?

Tags: mesh, edges, .fbx

I imported a FBX of a table. It is mostly various shaped boxes. But the rectangle faces have an edge running diagonally from 2 corner vertices. In screenshot, it shows one on the top of the table. What is the diagonal edge? And why is it black, when the other edges are light color?

[image]

Comment: "*But the rectangle faces have an edge running diagonally*" It is not a rectangle then, it is two triangles.

Comment: FYI - the reason the "triangle" edges are black while the rest are blue is that the blue edges appear to be marked "sharp". You can clear it (if you wish - may not be intended) by selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, right click and select "clear sharp".

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos -- thank you -- sometimes one does not recognize the obvious until it is pointed out by another (I find it more often as I get older :) )

Comment: @ChristopherBennett -- thank you -- so, whoever made this fbx used 2 triangles instead of a rectangle, and marked some edges as "sharp" but not others. I wonder if there is a name for this technique / approach?

Comment: It looks like the mesh was triangulated (or at least portions of it were) for some reason. If it's not the whole thing (ie, every face is split into 2 triangles), then I can't guess the reason for it. Often meshes are triangulated on export (and are almost always triangulated on import to a game engine), but usually it's the whole thing, not just "sections" of it. However, blender prefers quads, so if you're planning on using the mesh exclusively in blender, you may want to get rid of them. Also, marking "sharp" is often used to keep edges "tight" when smooth shading or using a subdiv modifier

Comment: @dl I work with a lot of CAD models inside of Blender, many times Cad models give you this result, triangulation everywhere and sharp edges everywhere... Maybe it is fbx itself because CAD models have no real topology and once they export it to fbx it makes these lines automatically... The thing that may help you is command called **Tris to Quads**, press F3 and search for it in edit mode with all faces selected

Comment: @MikoCG Thank you for extra insight (and C Bennett too). I think it may help with avoiding 'impossible quads', when the 4 vertices are not on the same plane. If they are converted to triangles, the 3 vertices establish the plane, so the face is not bent. The command to look for is awesome help -- would not have recognized that if I had seen it in the Menu or docs.